# Protect application files in from access by the same user

Tags: linux, non-root-user

I want to know if it's possible for an application to create files accessible only from the application itself. Problem is that I don't have root access.

For example, if I run the application as UserA I want to ensure that any other application run by UserA cannot access the files.

Comment: Do you want to prevent root-access, too?

Comment: No I don't want to prevent root access. But, if I run the application as UserA I want also that any other application runned from UserA cannot access the files. I think that something like creating a dummy user for the application would be what I need, but I don't have root access.

Comment: can you manage the information in memory instead of writing it to a file? That would effectively prevent something from writing to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the permissions on the files to: `0600` or set the `umask 077` for the user running the application the files will only be accessible by the application user and `root`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question...

Comment: It did in it's original form.

Answer (score 1):

In times past, and in systems without `proc(5)` mounted, a process could create and open a file, `unlink(2)` it, and have a valid, open handle to an anonymous file. No other process could name and therefore could not `open(2)` the file, even another process run by the same user (or root)

However, as most Linux systems have `/proc` mounted, even nameless files retain a name like `/proc/2757/fd/4` which is accessible to the other processes run by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

I currently can`t think of a way to achieve what you want without involving root. So: Contact your sysadmin and get a second account for your application.

Comment: I can't. This is an homework project and should run on the teacher pc and he explicitly said that the application should never ask for root access.

Comment: I suspect you either misunderstand the assignment or your instructor is not aware that the request is impossible to satisfy using conventional means. (Or, much less likely, the instructor knows of a non-standard, non-portable, method to make this work in a limited circumstance and wants to see if you can puzzle out the trick from thin air (I've seen more masochistic assignments, so it is *possible* but I think the first two guesses far more likely).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible directly; however, you could create a program (or a wrapper to that program) that checks information about its parent.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for an unprivileged process to create a file that it can read but other processes running as that user cannot.

Proof: suppose process A (unprivileged) has the file open, and process B (running as the same user) wants to open the file as well. Process B can call [`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) to take control of process A. The `ptrace` system call lets process B execute arbitrary code inside process A, including establishing a unix socket to process A and passing the open file descriptor over it (file descriptor passing is a feature of unix datagram sockets that, as the name indicates, allows the sender to send a file descriptor to the receiver, after which the receiver has the same file open in the same mode).

It's possible that what your professor intended is to open a file then delete it. A deleted file — technically, an unlinked file — cannot be opened by conventional means: No process (even a privileged one) can open it with the `open` system call, since there is no name that could be passed as an argument. But the process (or processes) that has the file open can continue working with it; the file will only actually be deleted when the last process that has it open dies. Other processes can still open a handle to the file by using `ptrace` as described above.

In addition to the `ptrace` method, on some unix variants including Linux, there may be [other ways to open a file that's opened in another process, through `/proc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30786/protect-application-files-in-from-access-by-the-same-user/30875#30875).